# Powershell - If this command returns value, send return code

Tags: powershell

Currently drafting a script for a RMM. I am checking Windows Defender for any threats found on the device using the Get-MpThreat powershell command. If there are no threats found, return a 0 code meaning nothing is wrong. If it returns say maybe a "1", then print out the output and return that code.

I have been brainstorming for maybe an hour or two on how to approach this and the only thing I have came up with is the opposite. The link of what I found before is linked below.

[powershell: if result is empty after a command, out some text](https://serverfault.com/questions/889202/powershell-if-result-is-empty-after-a-command-out-some-text)

Here is what I have so far, but it prints out the wrong things. My Defender does have threats detected so it should be printing out the error code of 1 not 0. The Write-Output is just for testing and will not be in the final script.

```
    #$ThreatDetection = $null;
$ThreatDetection = Get-MpThreat
    if ($ThreatDetection -ne $null){
        $exitcode = 0
        function ExitWithCode { param($exitcode) $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
        exit }
        Write-Output $exitcode
    }
    else {
        $exitcode = 1
        function ExitWithCode { param($exitcode) $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
        exit}
        Write-Output $exitcode

    }
```

Also I am not the greatest with powershell, python is my bread and butter but can't say the same about Powershell. any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Alright so I realized with a little bit more googling, I could have the solution. This is now my final solution for it and it appears to be working for me.

```
#$ThreatDetection = $null;
$ThreatDetection = Get-MpThreat
    if ($ThreatDetection -eq $null){
        $exitcode = 0
        function ExitWithCode { param($exitcode) $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
        exit }
    }
    else {
        $exitcode = 1
        function ExitWithCode { param($exitcode) $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
        exit}
    }
```

Second Edit: Nope this isnt working either. Changed the Return codes to different values and it still returns 0 or 1 for everything from the RMM perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the function multiple times instead of using it.

```powershell
function ExitWithCode { 
    param($exitcode) 
    $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
    exit 
}

$ThreatDetection = Get-MpThreat
if ($ThreatDetection -eq $null){
    ExitWithCode(0)
}

else {
    ExitWithCode(1)
}
```

But TBH, I don't know where you got that function. It seems completely unnecessary.

[`Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6#exit) accepts the return code as a parameter

This should be all that is necessary:

```powershell
$ThreatDetection = Get-MpThreat
if ($ThreatDetection -ne $null){
    Exit 1
}
```

You don't need `Exit 0`. Thats the default exit code.